# How to pull a defined number of clips to the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am in the process of creating a hidden object game in AS3.  For the most part it is working correctly.  The only problem I am seeing is that I want the code to pull exactly ten objects into a word list for the user to have to find within the scene.  I want the list to be random as well so the game will not get too mundane.  Right now, I have about 30 objects in the scene, but it is only pulling a maximum of three to the word list, if it pulls any at all.  Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
    var obArr:Array = new Array();
    var randArray:Array = new Array();
    var chkCnt:Number=10;

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, setupStage);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickOb);

    //set up current stage
    function setupStage(e:Event) {
    chkCnt=10;
    randArray.length=0;
    obArr=[];
//count the objects on stage
for (var n=0; n<gb1.numChildren; n++) {
    //get the children
    var ob=gb1.getChildAt(n);
//only take movie clips
    if (ob is MovieClip) {
//only count the movie clips that have name declared
    if (ob.myname!=null) {
//push to array
    obArr.push(MovieClip(ob));
        }
    }
}
//clear the list
nameslist.text="";
//build objects list
for (n=0; n<obArr.length; n++) {
    //add the name of object
    nameslist.appendText(String (obArr[n].myname));
    nameslist.appendText("\n\n");
}
//this is not needed anymore;
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, setupStage);
```

}

```
    //stage was clicked;
    function clickOb(e:MouseEvent) {
    var clicked=false;
//check which object was clicked
for (var n=0; n<obArr.length; n++) {
    //add the name of object
    if (obArr[n].hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY,true)) {
        //object is clicked
        clicked=true;
        //hide
        obArr[n].visible=false;
        //play sound
        ping.play();
        //remove from array
        obArr.splice(n,1);
    }
}
//rebuild text list
if (clicked) {
    //clear the list
    nameslist.text="";
    //build objects list
    for (n=0; n<obArr.length; n++) {
        //add the name of object
        nameslist.appendText(String (obArr[n].myname));
        nameslist.appendText("\n\n");
    }
    //check if array is empty meaning all objects were removed;
    if (n==0) {
        GB2Unlock.visible=true;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: it would easiest to just post your .fla

Answer (score 0):

Try listing objects in **obArr**, for example:

```
trace(obArr.length);
for (var i:int = 0; i < obArr.length; i++) {
    trace(obArr.name, obArr.myname);
}
```

Remember that **getChildAt** returns only objects that are on children of given parent **at the moment of execution**. So, if you add some object to stage later, for example on another frame, those objects will not be found by your method.

Comment: The stage itself is a movieclip, and the objects are all placed inside that clip.  Each object contains three of the same object to appear in three given positions.  For example, a bat might appear on a tree trunk, on top of a roof, or against a piece of wood.  The objects have their own script within them as well.  That code is as follows:

Comment: 'code' stop();

var randEnemy:Number;
var myname:String;
var cnt:Number=20;
var chk:Boolean=false;

if (parent.parent.chkCnt!=cnt) {
 randEnemy=Math.floor(Math.random()*4+1);
 for (var l:Number = 0; l < parent.parent.randArray.length; l++) {
  if (randEnemy==parent.parent.randArray[l]) {
   chk=true;
   l=10;
  } else {
   chk=false;
  }
 }
 if (chk==false) {
  parent.parent.randArray.push(randEnemy);
  switch (randEnemy) {
   case 1 :
    break;
   case 2 :
    parent.parent.chkCnt++;
    myname="Vampire Bat";
    gotoAndStop(2);
    break;

Comment: case 3 :
    parent.parent.chkCnt++;
    myname="Vampire Bat";
    gotoAndStop(3);
    break;
   case 4 :
    parent.parent.chkCnt++;
    myname="Vampire Bat";
    gotoAndStop(4);
    break;
  }
 }
}  I am not sure if the error in the object pull is on this code or the original one.  I have tried listing them by name already, and it got the same result.

Comment: please post your fla, it would be much easier

Comment: I am new to this forum. Can you tell me how to post the .fla?  I'm not seeing any upload section.